# should database tables reflect the api response as close to each other as possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, schema

- should I design the database with minimal joins but put things that don't get updated and handle it during insert for fast query select?
- or just join large tables against large tables?

Comment: Both ways can be useful. Again, depends if you query inside the response objects, and if the schema often changes

Comment: It's balance between designing for flexibility (being able to tackle varied unforeseen requests) and simpler design to respond to immediate, concrete requests. Also you may decide not to expose all internal details in the API; most of the time those are two separate things. Finally, the internal model and the public API will evolve in time; what you design today may differ considerably to what you'll have next year.

Comment: Perhaps neither. You should take some time and become familiar with **Data Normalization**.